# My Alarm Manager does not work in background

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I prepared for my application alarm manager. I need run this every hour and check if data is changed.

**I have set the alarm manager like this:**

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    android.app.AlarmManager alarmMgr = (android.app.AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AnalysisNotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, ALARM_ID, intent, 0);
    if (Calendar.getInstance().after(cal)) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

It's should work in every 60 minutes I'm not sure if I set correctly but doesn't work when app close.

Anyone have a idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, it worked for me

```
AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent scheduleServiceExecuterIntent = new Intent(this, ScheduledServiceExecuter.class);

scheduleServiceExecuterIntent.putExtra("state", "Main");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, request_code, intent, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please support me by giving an upvote.

Comment: I did it. Thanks.